# Bind values to label which is place within the listbox itemtemplate,Data template in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfIndexes}"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  x:Name="lstbxindex" SelectionMode="Extended" Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="201" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="80,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282" Background="#555555" >
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                  <Label x:Name="lblhr"  Height="40px" Width="80px" Content="{Binding Path=hrvalueinitially}" FontSize="20px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#555555"  Foreground="White"></Label>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="items"  Text="{Binding}" Margin="35,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is my XAML page code. I have to bind a value from code behind to XAML page.
created a label inside the data template, here label are creating dynamically at the run time. I need to bind the values form code behind file.

XAML.cs

```
 private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //check the listbox items is selected or not 
    if (lstbxindex.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        if (dispatcherTimer.Interval == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
        {
            double hrvalue = 0.25 + hrvalueinitially;

            //lblhr.Content= hrvalueinitially;
            hrvalueinitially = hrvalue;
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: You already have a binding to a view model property `hrvalueinitially`. Just change the value of that property.

Comment: How is `hrvalueinitially` defined?

Comment: I changed the property value.  <Label x:Name="lblhr"   Height="40px" Width="80px" Content="{Binding Path=hourval}" but value n't be binded to the label

Comment: Initially the hrvalueinitially declared as a global variable.like double hrvalueinitially;

Comment: Static? Well, thats not any good for a binding. How is `ListOfIndexes` defined? Best edit the property code into your question and if the items in the list have a specific type, include the relevant part of the type definition.

Comment: have you set DataContext ?? post full codes for updating ListOfIndexes